# Why can't I view database data output with Spring?

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I can't see my database data in my application in Spring
This is the complete code

pom.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.websparrow</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-mvc-crud</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>spring-mvc-crud Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- spring jdbc dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- mysql database connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- jstl library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>    
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>    
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>    
    <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>    
</dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>spring-mvc-crud</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

FrontControllerConfig.java

```js
package org.websparrow.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class FrontControllerConfig extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {

        return new Class[] { WebMvcConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {

        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

WebMvcConfig.java

```js
package org.websparrow.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.websparrow.dao.StudentDao;
import org.websparrow.dao.StudentDaoImpl;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("org.websparrow")
public class WebMvcConfig {

    @Bean
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {

        InternalResourceViewResolver vr = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        vr.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        vr.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return vr;
    }

    @Bean
    DriverManagerDataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springstudent1?useUnicode=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false");
        ds.setUsername("root");
        ds.setPassword("");

        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public StudentDao getUserDao() {
        return new StudentDaoImpl(getDataSource());
    }
}
```

ReadController.java

```js
package org.websparrow.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.websparrow.dao.StudentDao;
import org.websparrow.model.Student;

@Controller
public class ReadController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentDao studentDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/read")
    public ModelAndView readStudent(ModelAndView model) throws IOException {

        List<Student> listStudent = studentDao.read();
        model.addObject("listStudent", listStudent);
        model.setViewName("read");

        return model;
    }
}
```

StudentDao.java

```js
package org.websparrow.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.websparrow.model.Student;

public interface StudentDao {

    public List<Student> read();


}
```

StudentDaoImpl.java

```js
package org.websparrow.dao;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.websparrow.model.Student;

public class StudentDaoImpl implements StudentDao {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public StudentDaoImpl(DataSource dataSoruce) {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSoruce);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Student> read() {
        List<Student> studentList = jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM STUDENT1", new RowMapper<Student>() {

            @Override
            public Student mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                Student student = new Student();

                student.setId(rs.getInt("stu_id"));
                student.setName(rs.getString("stu_name"));
                student.setEmail(rs.getString("stu_email"));
                student.setCourse(rs.getString("stu_course"));

                return student;
            }

        });

        return studentList;
    }



}
```

Student.java

```js
package org.websparrow.model;

public class Student {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String course;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }
    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }
    
    

}
```

read.j

```js
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Read</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Spring MVC Create, Read, Update and Delete (CRUD) Example</h2>
    <p><strong>Student List is Here | <a href="create.jsp">Click for Create</a></strong></p>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Course</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="student" items="${listStudent}">
            <tr>
                <td>${student.id}</td>
                <td>${student.name}</td>
                <td>${student.email}</td>
                <td>${student.course}</td>
                <td><a href="update/<c:out value='${student.id}'/>">Update</a> | <a
                    href="delete/<c:out value='${student.id}'/>">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This instead as shown in the output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

try replacing this

```
<td>${student.id}</td>
```

with

```
<td><c:out value="${student.id}" /></td>
```

Comment: i tried to do this but the problem persists, i can't fix it

Comment: if you add console.log(listStudent) in your ReadController it will show data ? double check if your  returned object is not null

Comment: I tried to do it, i print this.                           
[org.websparrow.model.Student@7573e78a]                 
Why?

Comment: yes yes it printed out the object try printing one of its variables System.out.println(listStudent[0].getId()); or any other getName... if the object is filled from your db then the value should appear

Comment: where should this System.out.println go? I still know little about Java. I apologize. because if I put it in readController it gives me error

Comment: in fact it can be used inside any function and should not give an error double check the syntax in println it's a lower case L and you can use System.out.print

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/read")
    public ModelAndView readStudent(ModelAndView model) throws IOException {

        List<Student> listStudent = studentDao.read();
        model.addObject("listStudent", listStudent);
        System.out.println(listStudent[0].getId());
        model.setViewName("read");

        return model;
    }

Comment: don't forget [0] because it's a list and you're getting its first element to check its content

Comment: doing so gives me the following error:

"The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List <Student>"

Comment: System.out.println(listStudent.get(0).getId()); this should work

Comment: Yes perfect, now it works. It gives me the correct data, only I still couldn't resolve the error in the table

Comment: weird now you're sure that everything is fine from database and java side so try using addAttribute instead of addObject  and another thing you should try debugging your jsp file too

Comment: I solved it, the problem was very simple. I forgot to add the following line:
<%@page isELIgnored="false"%>.            thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

mark your Entity class as @Entity and perform import operation
import javax.persistence.Entity;